# pandas scatter plot and groupby does not work

Tags: pandas, scatter-plot

I am trying to do a scatter plot with pandas. Unfortunately `kind='scatter'` doesn't work. If I change this to `kind='line'` it works as expected. What can I do to fix this?

````
for label, d in df.groupby('m'):
    d[['te','n']].sort_values(by='n', ascending=False).plot(kind="scatter", x='n', y='te', ax=ax, label='m = '+str(label))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `plot.scatter` instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 5, 7,3, 2, 4, 6], 'y': [0, 5, 7,3, 2, 4, 6]})
df.plot.scatter('x', 'y')
```

[image: Output]

Use this snippet if you want individual labels and colours:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'm': np.random.randint(0, 5, size=100),
    'x': np.random.uniform(size=100),
    'y': np.random.uniform(size=100),
})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, d in df.groupby('m'):
    # generate a random color:
    color = list(np.random.uniform(size=3))
    d.plot.scatter('x', 'y', label=f'group {label}', ax=ax, c=[color])
```

[image: Different colours and labels]

Comment: Thank you, this works but the legend is not right. if i use the groupby, the labels for all groups are the same.

Comment: you can still set the label like before with `label='m = '+str(label)`.

Comment: i know, but they are all the same (so in my case they are all blue dots instead of being the color of my groups)

Comment: You should change the colour parameter then. Let me add a simple example

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Just one more thing, I get colours with low opacity, so you cannot see it that well. Is there a way to change this? or just choose 'r','g','k' for example.